# Parent & Child relation from single source

Tags: sql

My source table data is like below

[image: ID code code_name 1 A IN 2 B IN 3 C IN 4 D SP 5 E SP]

The output I'm looking is:

[image: parent_id child_id code_name 1 2 IN 1 3 IN 2 3 IN 4 5 SP]

Please can you help me...

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the output. Why are 2 and 3 the children of 1?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select b.id as parent_id,
       a.id as child_id,
       a.code_name
from table a
join table b on a.code_name = b.code_name
where a.id <> b.id and a.id > b.id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.